# Big Sur keeps deleting my cookies from Chrome (I tried to find the problem with Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, big-sur, cookies

Every time I start Chrome I have to login on all pages again, accept all cookie warnings etc. My cookies are not being saved.

So I have checked all Chrome settings (there are plenty of articles about cookie settings etc.), even uninstalled Chrome and all its files in ~/Library, tried Chrome for ARM and Intel, installed an older Chrome version but still the same issue. So I don't know where else to look for the problem in Chrome.

Is there any place I can look in my OS (Big Sur) for a solution? In Safari Cookies work fine.

EDIT:

I have now tried starting Chrome from the terminal a get the following error:

```
[2063:771:0702/102656.747042:ERROR:keychain_password_mac.mm(83)] Keychain lookup failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25304 "errKCInvalidItemRef / errSecInvalidItemRef:  / The item reference is invalid." (-25304)
```

I have found a solution...I will post the answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to delete all Chrome entries from the keychain tool.